# unable to use fetched data outside subscribe() method in angular 6

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services, subscribe, rxjs6

I am fetching an object from node server using a angular 6 service.

```
getMasterObj () {

   this.http.get(this.url1).subscribe(
        (data) =>{
        this.masterChartObj1 = data;
        console.log(this.masterChartObj1) // data is getting printed
    })
        console.log(this.masterChartObj1) // undefined

}
```

In same classs I have defined an object as

```
public masterChartObj1;
```

I am initializing that object with the data received in subscribe method.
as checked in console.log it is printed but same is undefined outside subscriber method.

I have tried same in another way also, but still same output.

```
 getMasterObj () {
       let parent_scope = this;
       this.http.get(this.url1).subscribe(
            (data) =>{
            parent_scope.masterChartObj1 = data;
            console.log(parent_scope.masterChartObj1) // data is getting printed
        })
            console.log(this.masterChartObj1) // undefined

    }
```

Please let me know, if I am doing anything wrong...

Comment: look for async vs sync.....

Comment: Becasue it's an async call.

Answer (score 1):

This is because observables are **asychronus**. **You are subscrbing to asynchronous data inside the subscribe method.** You can't access that data until it get initialized insde the subscribe method. That's why you are getting undefined

Answer (score 0):

This is because your method contains asyc method call.

```
this.http.get(this.url1).subscribe(
        (data) =>{
        this.masterChartObj1 = data;
        console.log(this.masterChartObj1) // data is getting printed
    })
```

This is an async call and Data once availabel it will print in `(data)` block.

So, if you want to add some binding to that data you need to do such task within the `data` block.